# Android multilingual activity label

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating app that works in 2 language. When language is changed, activity title-text will be changed programmitically and lang code will be saved in preferences. in the next opening, the app keep which the language that is used last time. all text in app displays text according to current lang except activity title.

I have string.xml in values and values-tr folder.

Manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name="uz.dictionary.sozluk.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".MySearch" />
    </activity>
```

@string/title has translation in values-tr. But, app is showing only default language. I don't want to do this programmitically, because when app is starting, first default label is showing, in few milliseconds changing to translation title if it's done by programmitically. 
How can I solve this problem?